# Change a many2one field content in onchange from another field?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

Im trying to change the content of a many2one field when another field trigger onchange method.

Heres my py code:

```
class proevent(osv.osv):
_name = 'proevent.events'
_description = 'Events Module'

def onchange_client(self,cr,uid,ids, client_id,sale_orders_ids,context=None):
    res={}
    order_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
    order_ids = order_obj.search(cr,uid, [('partner_id','=',client_id)])
    logging.info('LIST OF SALE ORDERS OF SELECTED PARTNER')
    logging.info(order_ids)
    res['sale_orders_ids'] = order_ids
    logging.info(res)
    return {'value':res}


_columns = {
    'eventdesc': fields.char('Evento', required=True),
    'client_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Cliente', required=True, change_default=True, select=True,track_visibility='always',domain=[('customer','=',True)]),
    'sale_orders_ids': fields.many2one('sale.order','Lista'),
    'eventaddress': fields.char('Direccion de Evento', required=True),
    'description': fields.char('Descripcion del Evento', required=True),
    'datein': fields.date('Fecha de Ingreso a Sistema', required=True, readonly=True),
    'setupdatein': fields.datetime('Inicio de Montaje', required=True),
    'setupdateout': fields.datetime('Fin de Montaje', required=True),
    'eventdatein': fields.datetime('Inicio de Evento', required=True),
    'eventdateout': fields.datetime('Fin de Evento', required=True),
    'eventnotes': fields.char('Notas del Evento', required=True),
    'readonlynote': fields.char('Nota'),
    'partner_rtn': fields.related('partner_id','RTN',type="char",relation="res.partner",string="RTN",store=True,readonly=True),


}
proevent()
```

When I select a client_id which is filtered to only show customers,in triggers onchange method and then my onchange_client function.

My problem is I can't make my sale_orders_ids many2one field to show only the sale order ids from the selected partner,it show all the sale orders of the system.

How can I populate my sale_order_ids field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def onchange_client(self,cr,uid,ids, client_id,sale_orders_ids,context=None):
    res={}
    order_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
    order_ids = order_obj.search(cr,uid, [('partner_id','=',client_id)])
    logging.info('LIST OF SALE ORDERS OF SELECTED PARTNER')
    logging.info(order_ids)
    return {'domain':{'sale_orders_ids':[('id','in',order_ids)]}}
```

you can do it with set domain on  many2one field.